# Confusion with how variables are evaluated in RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm at the stage of testing the `delete` action in my `hour` request spec. These set of requests are nested under the parent, `restaurant`. Therefore I've saved a global for the parent. Referencing this parent works anywhere for any of my tests.

For my deletion request I obviously have to provide an hour. Strangely the test only passes if I use `let!(:hour) {...}` vs. `let(:hour) {...}`. I realize that `let` with a `!` no longer lazy loads and fires on every test. The opposite of what I want. Why is there no problem with using `restaurant` and not `hour` for the test below?

```
RSpec.describe 'Hour', type: :request do
  let(:restaurant) {
    create(:restaurant)
  }

  let(:hour) {
    create(:hour)
  }

  describe "DELETE #destroy" do
    it "destroys the requested hour" do
      expect {
        delete admin_restaurant_hour_path(restaurant, hour)
      }.to change(Hour, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there no problem with using `restaurant` and not `hour` for the test below?

There is, the same "problem". It's just invisible to you, because you don't have any checks for it. Try this, for example:

```
expect { ... }.to_not change(Restaurant, :count)
```

Both those records do not exist prior to running the action, at the moment where `change` expectation writes down the initial value. `Hour.count` will be 0, because `hour` was not evaluated yet. Same for restaurants.

So either use `let!` or make sure to evaluate the records before setting up the expectation. Like this, for example:

```
it "destroys the requested hour" do
  restaurant; hour # poor man's let!
  expect {
    delete admin_restaurant_hour_path(restaurant, hour)
  }.to change(Hour, :count).by(-1)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. So just to clarify, when it comes to url helpers is the evaluation different than something like `change`? Just trying to understand why it would work in the helper `admin_restaurant_hour_path` and not err.

Comment: @CarlEdwards: not sure I understand what you're trying to ask. Could you rephrase?

Comment: Sure. So notice how I pass in `restaurant` and `hour` into `admin_restaurant_hour_path`. The helper is able to pick up on the newly initialized objects and make a successful request.  `change` does not pick up on them for the reasons you've explained. Why is that the case for the url helper? Does that make sense?

Comment: @CarlEdwards: "Why is that the case for the url helper?" - because method's arguments are evaluated before the call. Same as in all of ruby.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much for clearing things up for me.

Comment: @max: if that were the case, how would `change` know what values they were before the action?